# SMART test fixed itself after a few runs

Tags: ssd, smartctl

I found something bizarre to me:

```
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      8003         -
# 2  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%      8001         5907400
# 3  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%      8001         5907400
# 4  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%      8001         5907400
# 5  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%      8001         5907400
# 6  Short offline       Completed: read failure       80%      8001         5907400
# 7  Short offline       Completed: read failure       80%      8000         5907400
# 8  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%         1         -
```

I had the drive throw a ton of ATA errors with data being unreadable. I decided to RMA it, so I ran `hdparm` secure erase procedure as well as tossed a `shred` over it. As this is a small (500GB Samsung EVO) SSD it went relatively fast. I ran another `smartctl -t short` and... it "fixed" itself.

The drive still has `ATA Error Count: 207` with the following attributes:

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   075   075   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       123
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       8004
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       27
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0013   099   099   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       4
179 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot   0x0013   075   075   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       123
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0013   075   075   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       123
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       207
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0032   060   051   000    Old_age   Always       -       40
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   199   199   000    Old_age   Always       -       207
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
235 Unknown_Attribute       0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       12
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       3737223587
```

What caused the SMART test to "fix" itself out of a sudden? I don't think the drive can be trusted anymore? However, I doubt Samsung will RMA it now as it's not failing the test...

*edit: for completeness of the story, Samsung did replace the drive with a brand new one.*

Comment: they will definitely still accept an rma the drive.  there is extra storage inside the ssd so a few cells can die before the drive cannot recover.  all the data on an ssd is  mapped internally so they can do things like wear leveling to keep drives alive longer, even if you are writing to the same location over and over.   I have seen the same thing with a samsung ssd, where it had some failures that just went away.   I decided to keep it because it is still reliable, but I trust it slightly less then my other ssds.  if you lost data, then I would rma it for sure.

Comment: Will try to RMA It regardless. While it doesn't fit into the question itself, I asked around and quite a few people had these 870 EVOs fail in a similar manner with just around 1-2TBW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is stored together with error correction information that allows correction of a number of bit errors, and detection of a (higher) number of bit errors.

The simple case would be a majority vote among four bits:

```
0000 - '0', no error
0001 - '0', 1 error
0010 - '0', 1 error
0011 - uncorrectable
0100 - '0', 1 error
0101 - uncorrectable
0110 - uncorrectable
0111 - '1', 1 error
1000 - '0', 1 error
1001 - uncorrectable
1010 - uncorrectable
1011 - '1', 1 error
1100 - uncorrectable
1101 - '1', 1 error
1110 - '1', 1 error
1111 - '1', 0 errors
```

This method allows correction of 1 error, and detection of 2 errors. If you have 3 errors, you will get the wrong result. Of course, the actual method uses larger groups, so it expands data only by a few percent, not by a factor of 4, also taking into account that errors are usually clustered together.

So an "uncorrectable" error is not necessarily bad media, it just means that data is unrecoverable right now. Overwriting the data can easily repair that, and my suspicion is that is what happened.

Before an error is shown, usually several attempts to read it are made. If one of these attempts succeeds, then the block is remapped, and shows up in the `Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot`. Since the raw value of 123 is translated to 75, I'd expect that roughly a quarter of reserved blocks are used, so probably around 500 exist. This attribute will go to `FAILING_NOW` state when 10% of blocks are left, so around 50.

So yes, I believe that SSD is somewhat dodgy, as it has been picking up a number of reallocated sectors in addition to the read failures.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense actually... since it's a QLC it couldn't distinguish the signal for old data but the cells may still be good-ish. I guess the drive will be dumped as temp/scratch or put into a mirror if they refuse to RMA it.